# Handling simple change request with login form in Play Framework

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework

I've been familiarizing myself with Play Framework in Java. I took on a fairly simple change request for an application, but I don't think I fully understand how to go about fixing it. The request is to repopulate the email field after a failed login attempt. I realize it's probably a pretty simple fix but I wasn't able to find a solution for this particular situation. Here's what I've found

Routes file:

```
#Sessions
GET         /logout        @femr.ui.controllers.SessionsController.delete()
POST        /login/reset   @femr.ui.controllers.SessionsController.editPasswordPost()
POST        /login         @femr.ui.controllers.SessionsController.createPost()
GET         /login         @femr.ui.controllers.SessionsController.createGet()
```

Code Snippit within SessionsController.java (Commented lines are my attempted fix):

```
public Result createPost() {

    final Form<CreateViewModel> createViewModelForm = formFactory.form(CreateViewModel.class);
    CreateViewModel viewModel = createViewModelForm.bindFromRequest().get();
    ServiceResponse<CurrentUser> response = sessionsService.createSession(viewModel.getEmail(), viewModel.getPassword(), request().remoteAddress());

    if (response.hasErrors()) {
        //CreateViewModel emailModel = new CreateViewModel();
        //emailModel.setEmail(viewModel.getEmail());
        //createViewModelForm.fill(emailModel);
        return ok(create.render(createViewModelForm));
    }
```

Here I'm attempting to fill in the email field before rendering the form, but it didn't quite do the trick. I looked online and saw something about doing an explicit render but that didn't quite work for me either.

The form I found is create.scala.html and I believe the solution may involve using javascript or something in this, but I'd like to handle it just in the SessionController in Java if possible.
Suggestions welcome!

Comment: When you bind the from with the data from the request if you pass it to your view again it will "keep" the data on the form. And if you wanna send a message or something similar you can send a flash on the response and read it on your view too.

Comment: You gotta remember that play is stateless so every request is anew one and you gotta render the data again.